# Convert char* to uint8_t

Tags: c++, char, data-conversion, uint8t

I transfer **message trough a CAN protocol**.

To do so, the **CAN message needs data of uint8_t type**. So I need to convert my char* to uint8_t. With my research on this site, I produce this code :

```
    char* bufferSlidePressure = ui->canDataModifiableTableWidget->item(6,3)->text().toUtf8().data();//My char*

    /* Conversion */
    uint8_t slidePressure [8];
    sscanf(bufferSlidePressure,"%c",
        &slidePressure[0]);
```

As you may see, my `char*` must fit in `sliderPressure[0]`.

My problem is that even if I have no error during compilation, **the data in slidePressure are totally incorrect**. Indeed, I test it with a `char* = 0` and I 've got unknow characters ... So I think the problem must come from conversion.

My datas can be `Bool, Uchar, Ushort and float`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "char* = 0" means "bufferSlidePressure == 0"? If so, no data will be converted.

Comment: It means bufferSlidePressure = '0'

Comment: please present the specific input& output value. The following code can show the right value: `char* buf = "0";  uint8_t slide[8];  sscanf(buf, "%c", &slide[0]);  printf("%d", slide[0]); `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is your string an integer? E.g. `char* bufferSlidePressure = "123";`?

If so, I would simply do:

```
uint8_t slidePressure = (uint8_t)atoi(bufferSlidePressure);
```

Or, if you need to put it in an array:

```
slidePressure[0] = (uint8_t)atoi(bufferSlidePressure);
```

Edit: Following your comment, if your data could be anything, I guess you would have to copy it into the buffer of the new data type. E.g. something like:

```
/* in case you'd expect a float*/
float slidePressure;
memcpy(&slidePressure, bufferSlidePressure, sizeof(float));

/* in case you'd expect a bool*/
bool isSlidePressure;
memcpy(&isSlidePressure, bufferSlidePressure, sizeof(bool));

/*same thing for uint8_t, etc */

/* in case you'd expect char buffer, just a byte to byte copy */
char * slidePressure = new char[ size ]; // or a stack buffer 
memcpy(slidePressure, (const char*)bufferSlidePressure, size ); // no sizeof, since sizeof(char)=1
```

Comment: Yes it can be, but it also can be a boolean or a float, is this work the same way ?

Comment: @EvansBelloeil If I understand correctly, I would probably do something using `memcpy()` (see my edit).

Comment: It seems okay, but I also need have char * now :(

Comment: @EvansBelloeil No conversion needed then :) See edit.

Comment: Thanks but I need this char* in format uint8_t, the compilator doesn't accept your answer :( and told me there's an invalid conversion from char * to uint8_t

Comment: @EvansBelloeil Then change `char` to `uint8_t` in my last example and that should work. If you want to copy to one `uint8_t`, then `size=1`. Otherwise you copy a series of `uint8_t`. See also [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

uint8_t is 8 bits of memory, and can store values from 0 to 255

char is probably 8 bits of memory

char * is probably 32 or 64 bits of memory containing the address of a different place in memory in which there is a char

First, make sure you don't try to put the memory address (the char *) into the uint8 - put what it points to in:

```
char from;
char * pfrom = &from;
uint8_t to;
to = *pfrom;
```

Then work out what you are really trying to do ... because this isn't quite making sense.  For example, a float is probably 32 or 64 bits of memory.  If you think there is a float somewhere in your char * data you have a lot of explaining to do before we can help :/

Answer (score 0):

`char *` is a pointer, not a single character. It is possible that it points to the character you want.

`uint8_t` is unsigned but on most systems will be the same size as a `char` and you can simply cast the value.

You may need to manage the memory and lifetime of what your function returns. This could be done with `vector< unsigned char>` as the return type of your function rather than `char *`, especially if toUtf8() has to create the memory for the data.

Your question is totally ambiguous.

```
ui->canDataModifiableTableWidget->item(6,3)->text().toUtf8().data();
```

That is a lot of cascading calls. We have no idea what any of them do and whether they are yours or not. It looks dangerous.

Comment: The cast doesn't work :(  uint8_t slidePressure = (uint8_t) bufferSlidePressure;

Comment: no, you cast the data inside, but it's totally impossible to work out what you are trying to do

Answer (score -1):

More safe example in C++ way

```
char* bufferSlidePressure = "123";
std::string buffer(bufferSlidePressure);
std::stringstream stream;

stream << str;
int n = 0;

// convert to int
if (!(stream >> n)){
    //could not convert
}
```

Also, if boost is availabe

```
int n = boost::lexical_cast<int>( str )
```